# What is an example of pairwise independent random variables which are not independent?

Tags: probability-theory, discrete-mathematics

I've just read in a stochastics textbook:

> Let $(\Omega, P)$ be a discrete probability space.
>
> (a) The events $A_i \subseteq \Omega, i=1,2, \dots$ are called **independent**, if
>   $$P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2} \cap \dots \cap A_{i_k}) = P(A_{i_1}) \cdot \dots \cdot A_{i_k}$$
>   for all finite sets $\{i_1, \dots, i_k\} \subsetneq \{1,2, \dots\}$ and all $k \geq 2$.
>
> (b) The events $A_i \subseteq \Omega, i=1,2,\dots$ are called **pairwise independent**, if
>   $$P(A_{i_1} \cap A_{i_2}) = P(A_{i_1}) \cdot P(A_{i_2})$$
>   for all pairs $\{i_1, i_2\} \subsetneq \{1,2,\dots\}$.

After these two definitions it states that pairwise independent events are not always independent.

Do you have an example?

Comment: Please note that English is not my mother tongue and the textbook is written in German. Please correct my mistakes if I used the wrong terms (e.g. I'm not sure if it is called "event" in English).

Comment: German Wikipedia has [this example](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastische_Unabh%C3%A4ngigkeit#Beispiel_2).

Comment: My favourite formulation of Michael's standard example is to let $X$ be a uniformly random angle and take the events $\sin(X)>0$, $\cos(X)>0$, $\tan(X)>0$.

Comment: My favourite formulation of Michael's standard example (which has been posted maaany times on the site) is to let $X_1=U$, $X_2=V$, $X_3=UV$, with $U$ and $V$ i.i.d. uniform on $\{-1,+1\}$. This generalizes to higher dimensions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I am just rewriting my comment above in the form of an answer).

A standard example is to define $X_1, X_2$ as independent Bernoulli random variables with $Pr[X_i=1]=Pr[X_i=0]=1/2$ for $i \in \{1,2\}$, and define $X_3 = X_1 + X_2 \mod 2$.  Then $X_3$ is dependent on $\{X_1,X_2\}$, so $\{X_1,X_2,X_3\}$ are not mutually independent.  However, any two out of the three random variables are independent. That is, $\{X_1, X_2\}$ are independent, $\{X_2,X_3\}$ are independent, and $\{X_1,X_3\}$ are independent.