# A surprisingly tricky question regarding conditional expectation

Tags: measure-theory, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation

Let $S_n := X_1 + \dots + X_n$ for some i.i.d. r.v. $X_i$ (specifics not so important) and let $f$ be a function satisfying

\begin{align} 
Ef(x+X_1) = f(x).
\end{align}
Then, as always the following would hold
\begin{align}
E\left(f(S_n + X_{n+1}) \vert X_1, \dots X_n\right) = f(S_n) \quad \text{(correct?)}
\end{align}
Now, what if we additionally have some r.v. $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ depending on $X_1, \dots, X_n$ in some way but independent of $X_{n+1}$ and consider
\begin{align}
E\left( f(S_n + X_{n+1}) \vert X_1,\dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots, Y_n\right),
\end{align}
is this still equal to $f(S_n)$?

It is weird that I have never thought about this before... Also, this question could probably be asked in a more general form, but I thought giving a hands-on example might make it more palpable.

**Edit:** As was correctly pointed out, I should've been clearer: The $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ are not stochastically independent of the $X_1, \dots, X_n$. They're **not** measurebale functions of the $X_1, \dots, X_n$.

Comment: By "depending on $X_1,\ldots,X_n$ in some way", do you mean that the $Y_i$ are functions of the $X_i$? Or just that they're not independent of them?

Comment: That they are not independent. Thanks for clarifying that.

Comment: $Y_n$ can be independent of $X_{n+1}$, and $X_n$ can be independent of $X_{n+1}$, while $X_{n+1}$ depends on $(X_n,Y_n)$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. So, with the additional condition that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of (X_1, \dots, X_n, Y_1, \dots, Y_n) the statement is true, correct?

Comment: @BenC. : Yes, the d.k.o. answer treats the case when $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $(X_1, ..., X_n, Y_1,..., Y_n)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, if $\mathcal{G}$ is a $\sigma$-field s.t. $S$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and $X$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$, then for any integrable function $\varphi$, $\mathsf{E}[\varphi(S,X)\mid \mathcal{G}]=g(S)$ a.s., where $g(s):=\mathsf{E}\varphi(s,X)$. Apply this result to your case with $\mathcal{G}=\sigma\{X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n\}$, assuming that $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $\mathcal{G}$ (see @Michael's comments and examples [1](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2029257/examples-of-pairewise-independent-but-not-independent-continuous-random-variable), [2](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1783225/example-of-pairwise-independent-but-not-jointly-independent-random-variables), and [3](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1143256/what-is-an-example-of-pairwise-independent-random-variables-which-are-not-indepe)).

Comment: Thanks! Makes sense... I guess, it is considered common knowledge then?

Comment: @BenC. See, for example Lemma 6.2.1 on page 236 [here](https://www.ime.usp.br/~manuelg/arquivos/Probability:%20Theory%20and%20Examples%20-%20Durrett.pdf).

Comment: Oh wow, perfect! Thanks a lot for the quick response!

Comment: Wait a minute, wouldn't I be stuck with $Ef(S_n, X_{n+1})$ in my case, which is not neccessarily $f(S_n)$? My function $f$ is only specified to satisfy $E(f(x+X_{n+1})) = f(x) $ for real numbers $x$.

Comment: In your case $\varphi(S_n,X_{n+1})=f(S_n+X_{n+1})$ and $\mathsf{E}\varphi(S_n,X_{n+1})=f(S_n)$...

Comment: With the problem as stated, there is no reason that $X_{n+1}$ should be independent of $\sigma(X_1,...,X_n,Y_1,...,Y_n)$, (see my comment above).

Comment: @Michael Thnx for pointing that out.

Answer (score 2):

If $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$ are measurable functions of $X_1,\ldots,X_n$, then $\sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n) = \sigma(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$. 
Hence 
$$\mathbb E[f(S_n + X_{n+1})| X_1,\ldots,X_n,Y_1,\ldots,Y_n] = \mathbb E[f(S_n + X_{n+1}) | X_1,\ldots,X_n ] = \big.\int f(x+y) dQ_{X_{n+1}}(y)\big|_{y=S_n} = f(S_n) $$

Comment: Yeah, sorry. It was meant to mean that $Y_1, \dots,Y_n$ are not stochastically independent of the $X_1, \dots, X_n$.

Comment: the answer is the same since $X_{n+1}$ is independent of $Y_1,\ldots,Y_n$.